# How to instantiate C++ objects on specific NUMA memory nodes?

Tags: c++, numa

Simple C code can use `libnuma` library to allocate memory in specific memory node in a NUMA system. For example, it can be done using following function:

```
void *numa_alloc_onnode(size_t size, int node)
```

How one instantiate a class in some memory node? One way, I can think of is:

```
numa_set_membind(<nodemask>);
o = new Object();
numa_set_localalloc();
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) is what you are looking for. Example:

```
void *blob = numa_alloc_onnode(sizeof(Object), ...);
Object *object = new(blob) Object;
```

Comment: Although do be careful about alignment requirements.

Comment: How do you deallocate?

Comment: Also, apparently one has to free using `numa_free()`, so to be complete:
    `object->~Object();
    numa_free(blob);`

Comment: @BenVoigt: How does one align properly?

Comment: @shoban Here is a [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154162/numa-aware-cache-aligned-memory-allocation) question about how to do aligned allocations with numa

Comment: @shoban, `numa_alloc_onnode` returns page-aligned memory, therefore you don't have to do anything special in addition.

Comment: @HristoIliev The man page is not explicit about it. I guess the following excerpt from man page makes what you are saying implicit: "The size argument will be rounded up to a multiple of the system page size."