# Thread Affinity also restrict memory allocation?

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, memory-management

I am currently working on a NUMA system with two CPUs. The memory access time is not the same for the two CPUs.

I have used `PTHREAD_SETAFFINITY_NP` to assign threads to specific CPUs:

```
int stick_this_thread_to_core(int core_id) {
  int num_cores = sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN);//number of processors
  if (core_id < 0 || core_id >= num_cores)
     return EINVAL;
  cpu_set_t mask;
  CPU_ZERO(&mask);
  CPU_SET(core_id, &mask);
  pthread_t current_thread = pthread_self();    
  return pthread_setaffinity_np(current_thread, sizeof(cpu_set_t), &mask);
}
```

My question is, does it also restrict the memory allocation of the thread? For example, if I `malloc` in the thread running in CPU-1, will the memory be allocated in memories of CPU-1 only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't count on it.  In windows, you have to use special functions to allcate memory on a particular numa node.  Linux is pretty similar.  Look for a memory mapping function in linux that takes the numa node.

EDIT:
numa_malloc

See this link

[NUMA aware cache aligned memory allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8154162/numa-aware-cache-aligned-memory-allocation)